# Is there exist a continuous onto function $f : S^1 \rightarrow S^2 $ or $S^2 \rightarrow S^1$? Yes/no

Tags: general-topology

$1. $ Is  there  exist  a  continuous onto function  $f : S^1 \rightarrow S^2 $?

$2.$ Is there exist a continuous onto function  $f : S^2 \rightarrow S^1$?

My thinking : I thinks in both cases $1$ and $2$ it is not possible    because $S^2$ minus two points is connected while $S^1$ minus two points isn‘t.

Comment: Your thinking shows that $S^1$ and $S^2$ are not homeomorphic. But considering for example a continuous onto function $f\colon S^2\to S^1$, the preimage of two points in $S^1$ might be infinitely many points in $S^2$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman  im not  getting  can u elaboarte more in  answer box

Comment: Yes from $S^2 \to S^1$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054204/does-there-exist-a-continuous-onto-function-from-s2-to-s1).

Comment: And yes from $S^1$ to $S^2$ using a "space-filling curve".

Comment: Continuous surjections do not preserve much. For example any non-empty space can be continuously mapped onto  a 1-point pace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t\in [0,\pi]$ let $f_1(\cos t,\sin t)=t/\pi.$ For $t\in [\pi,2\pi]$ let $f_1(\cos t, \sin t)=(2\pi-t)/\pi.$

There exists a continuous surjection $f_2:[0,1]\to  [0,1]^2.$ See "Peano  Curve" in Wikipedia.

For $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$ let $f_3(x,y)=(\cos 2\pi x, \sin 2\pi x \cos \pi y, \sin 2\pi x \sin \pi y).$

Now $f=f_3f_2f_1$ is a continuous surjection from $S^1$ to  $S^2.$

Comment: @PaulFrost  $[0,1]^2$ IS the range of $f_2$. It's a SURjection.

Comment: @PaulFrost . Thank you. That was a typo. Typo is my native language.

Comment: Perhaps you have another typo, do you mean $f=f_3\circ (f_2\times f_1)$ instead of $f=f_3f_2f_1$? Or, possibly $f=f_3\circ (f_1\times f_2)$. Also, you edited so now $f_3$ is a function of two variables (if you look at the domain), but also of three variables (if you look at the definition).

Comment: @Mirko . Yes, another typo. In the 1st line $f$ should have been $ f_1$.....$f_1$ maps $S^1$ to $[0,1]$ and $f_2$  maps $ [0,1] $ to $[0,1]^2$ and $f_3$ maps $[0,1]^2$ to $S^2.$